# Adding points when joining two datasets together in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins

I am trying to join an excel file with a shapefile based on a zipcode. My problem is that I have multiple persons with the same zip code, but it joins only 1 of those persons.

Is it possible to automatically add multiple points when trying to join several persons from the excel file with my shapefile (which only has one zip code point)?

Comment: does a relate help you, or do you necessarily need to create multipoints ? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002v000000

Comment: No, unfortunatly I need to create multipoints. I am going to use these points in an agent based model, which needs unique points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround, (but of course it would be cleaner to do it with an insertcursor in Python).

1) Add the X andd Y coordinates for your points (from field calculator, or with the tool in Data management > features)

2) join the table of your point on your excel file

3) export the excel file to another table, and add it as point using "Make XY event layer"